# $(this).attr('href') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK I know there are a lot of posts about JQuery .attr being undefined but I haven't been able to find one that solves or even gives me a hint as to what is going wrong here.

First I have an Ajax request that fills a ul as follows.

```
$.each(msg,function(key, value){
            ul.append('<li class="fa fa-angle-right cnt-link"><a href="'+key+'">'+value+'</a></li>');
        })
```

That works fine creates the list and the href tries to go to the non-existent page that is set by the key value.

When the link is clicked though I'm trying to do another AJAX request using that href value but for some reason, I am unable to get the value from it.

```
$('.cnt-link').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var cnt = $(this).text();
            var cntId = $(this).attr('href');               
            console.log(cntId);
            console.log(cnt);
        })
```

the cnt variable is being set fine so I can't see how it would be a problem with $(this) not referencing the correct object but trying to get the href returns undefined.

I also tried adding the key value using

```
ul.append('<li class="fa fa-angle-right cnt-link"><a href="#">'+value+'</a></li>').data("cntId", key);
```

and retrieving it from the clicked item with

```
var cntId = $(this).data('cntId');
```

But this also returns undefined so that made me start thinking maybe it is something about $(this) not selecting the correct object.

I'm at my wits end with this and would greatly appreciate some input from anyone who can see what stupid mistake I am making :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you SOOOO much.  I knew it was going to be something truly stupid I was overlooking and you are spot on.  It didn't even occur to me that the <li> and <a> would both have the same text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cnt-link` is a `<li>` so it has no `href` attribute. If you want to get the `href` inside the `li` created with the code

```
ul.append('<li class="fa fa-angle-right cnt-link"><a href="'+key+'">'+value+'</a></li>');
```

then you might select `a`s which are children of `.cnt-link`s instead, and `this` will refer to an `a` with a `href`:

```
$('.cnt-link > a').click(function(event){
```

Or, with a handler on the `.cnt-link`, select the `.cnt-link`'s `.children` first to get to the `<a>`:

```
$('.cnt-link').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var cntId = $(this).children().attr('href');               
  console.log(cntId);
})
```

```js
$('.cnt-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var cntId = $(this).children().attr('href');
  console.log(cntId);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="fa fa-angle-right cnt-link"><a href="somelink">foobar</a></li>
</ul>
```